# Spotipy :: fail to get audio features for tracks

Tags: python, spotipy

I'm trying to fetch `audio_features` for several tracks. I'm using this:

```
client_credentials_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id='myid', client_secret='mysecret')
sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manager)
sp.trace=False

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    artist_name = ' '.join(sys.argv[1:])
    results = sp.search(q=artist_name, limit=50)
    tids = []
    for i, t in enumerate(results['tracks']['items']):
        print(' ', i, t['name'])
        tids.append(t['uri'])

    start = time.time()
    features = sp.audio_features(tids)
    delta = time.time() - start
    for feature in features:
        analysis = sp._get(feature['analysis_url'])
        print(json.dumps(analysis, indent=4))
        print()
```

But when I run the code, I get:

```
features = sp.audio_features(tids)
AttributeError: 'Spotify' object has no attribute 'audio_features'
```

What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the most recent version? Is this `spotipy.Spotify` the same as the `spotipy.client.Spotify`? Because that one has `audio_features`.

Comment: nailed it. `spotipy` was outdated. thanks